# JSF 2 DataTable with multiple headers on dynamic columns

Tags: jsf-2, header, dynamic-columns, view-scope

I'm developing a data-centric Web Application using JSF 2.1 and PrimeFaces 3.4.
As a result of a specific query, I must display the results in a bi-dimensional data table with some dynamic columns (imagine a sort of Pivot-table).
Currently I use a PrimeFaces `<p:dataTable>` with some standard `<p:column>` tags and a `<p:columns>` for the dynamically-created columns. The table is backed by a `@ViewScoped` Managed Bean.
It works fine, but:

- Just like a pivot-table, I need to display multiple headers too, in
  order to group some fields together. Unfortunately, `<p:columns>` is
  not compatible with `<p:columnGroup>` (nor with many other features
  like resizing etc.)
- I need to display some custom sub-total rows (is there a way to
  do this?)

I was thinking about populating the entire `<p:dataTable>` programmatically, but I can't use `binding="#{...}"` with a `@ViewScoped` bean due to [JSF issue 1492](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1492).

Comment: The issue has been resolved in the latest version of mojarra. Upgrade and see

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I see it will be fixed in JSF 2.2, am I missing something?